# Session Management in asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm using asp.net core 3.1 MVC
to log in to the system, i'm using (AspNetCore.Identity) package. when I run the application on the localhost, it's working fine. but once i upload it to the server, the issue rises again. the user can't stay logged-in. I tried to configure the session management on top of that. in the startup file, i use the code :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //Session Configuration
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //TODO: Change Environment in launchSettings.json to Production before publishing the application.
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        //Use Session
        app.UseResponseCaching();
        app.UseSession();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

in the controllers, i use the following :

```
private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        private const string SessionUser = "_User";
        private const string SessionRole = "_Role";
```

The user is now able to login, but the issue still remain the same where the system logs the user out.

Kindly help in that, and thank you in advance.

Comment: where do you store identity data, in some database? (if not, suggest you try such as sqlite)

Comment: Thanks Lei Yang .. I store it in MSSQL DB

Comment: 'the user can't stay logged-in' --- can you specify the detailed steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: 1. user login. - 2. log indicates a successful login. 3. once the request back to the main page, it shows that no user is logged in as if no credentials were input. 4. somehow using session management in the question above, the user could stay logged-in in some pages, but when the user tries to make actions; the system logged the user out, and it takes him to the login page again.

Comment: Hi @MohaBahusayn, from your code, it seems you do not use anything with Identity.

Comment: @MohaBahusayn where is ur `Session management` class for managing ur logged in user identity? i think maybe there is a problem on there

Answer (score -1):

Please check the token Info [JWT](https://jwt.io/) you can copy paste your token and find out the expiry time and claims Info of your portal for managing your session.

Comment: this is not related to my question, dear priyanka :)

Comment: @MohaBahusayn Oh ya I thought Identity server you meant.